# Adding a series of numbers through input

Tags: java

I want the numbers to add but only in between the leaders designated. For example if letters B and E are inputed i want 630 to be outputted. I want it to add from B all the way to E, but not including E. So the program would add (140+125+365), it doesn't include the last number. Another example would be if C and G are inouted it would output 125+365+250+160).

```
System.out.println("enter location 1");
        String location1=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter location 2");
        String location2=in.nextLine();
if (location1.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))

        {
         sum +=450;
        }
        else if (location1.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
        {
            sum+=140;
        }

        else if (location1.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
        {
            sum+=125;
        }

        else if (location1.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
        {
            sum+=125;
        }
        else if (location1.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
        {
            sum+=365;
        }
        else if (location1.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
        {
            sum+=160;
        }
        else if (location1.equalsIgnoreCase("g"))
        {
            sum+=380;
        }
        else if (location1.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))
        {
            sum+=235;
        }
        else if (location1.equalsIgnoreCase("j"))
        {
            sum+=320;
        }
        else if (location1.equalsIgnoreCase("k"))
        {
            sum+=0;
        }

    if (location2.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))

        {
         sum2 +=450;
        }
        else if (location2.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
        {
            sum2+=140;
        }

        else if (location2.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
        {
            sum2+=125;
        }

        else if (location2.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
        {
            sum2+=365;
        }
        else if (location2.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
        {
            sum2+=250;
        }
        else if (location2.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
        {
            sum2+=160;
        }
        else if (location2.equalsIgnoreCase("g"))
        {
            sum2+=380;
        }
        else if (location2.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))
        {
            sum2+=235;
        }
        else if (location2.equalsIgnoreCase("j"))
        {
            sum2+=320;
        }
        else if (location2.equalsIgnoreCase("k"))
        {
            sum2+=0;
        }
```

Comment: Stack overflow is NOT a homework writing service! When you're asking professional and enthusiast programmers to solve your problem, you need to state which part of it isn't working as expected and why, and state what you have done to solve the problem already. What is your actual question?

Comment: I said that whenever i would input C or E it would just be C and E not D as well. I have over 500 lines in this program and this one part isn't working. I can show you the rest if you would like. And it isn't homework either.

Comment: Holy s*** you are going to love it when you discover maps as a data structure.

Comment: NEVER show any more code than is required to reproduce the problem if you want help.

Comment: Also, I see "_I want it to add from B all the way to E, but not including E._" which I read as meaning you want to add b + c + d but then you say it should be b + c + e. Which is it?

Comment: This isnt all the code, its just the problematic zone that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: No i gave another example of C+G not C+E so it might be easier to understand. I want it to pull all the numbers between the two but not including the location of the 2nd location.

Answer (score 1):

An `if` statement only executes the branch where the condition is true. If you enter 'd', then only the `else if (location2.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))` is true and only that number is added. If you want all numbers "between" two letters, you could first treat the letters as `char`s, then have a loop from the lower to the higher one, and add whatever numbers you have for each.

As @Takendarkk said, a map would probably be helpful. Here I'd use a linked map (preserves order).  Here is some untested pseudo code:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

// ...

LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> valuePerCharacter = new LinkedHashMap<>();
valuePerCharacter.put('a', 450);
valuePerCharacter.put('b', 140);
// ... and so on...

int sum = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e : valuePerCharacter.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getKey() >= location1 && e.getKey() < location2) {
         sum += e.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: for your methods, like getValue and getKey what would go inside those methods? Would I just make a seperate class and just make a getValue and getKey methods getting the number and letter of each input?

Comment: `getKey` and `getValue` are methods of `Map.Entry`. You don't need to write them, just use them. Just import `java.util.Map`.

Comment: It says that e.getKey is undefined for the type integer, but e.valuePerCharacter.values()) only works with integer in front of it, any ideas?

Comment: Well, it was meant as pseudo code... I've updated my answer to real code.